# vba code not giving sum values

Tags: vba, excel, sum

I am writing an excel vba sub routine that sums up lbs purchased by customer per year, but for some reason the subroutine is failing. It prints out all of the customer names in the column `B` as it should but for the year 2011 it prints all `0`'s in that row and for 2012, 2013, and 2014 it prints `0`'s in the first column and thats it.

```
Private Sub lbsPerCustPerYear_Click()
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim Cust As Range
  Dim Cust2 As Range
  Dim Total2011 As Long
  Dim Total2012 As Long
  Dim Total2013 As Long
  Dim Total2014 As Long
  Dim Output As Range
  Dim OutputY2011 As Range
  Dim OutputY2012 As Range
  Dim OutputY2013 As Range
  Dim OutputY2014 As Range
  Dim CustLbs As Range
  Dim Cust2Lbs As Range
  Dim YearD As Range

  Total = 0
  Set Cust = Range("C6")
  Set Cust2 = Range("C7")
  Set CustLbs = Range("Q6")
  Set Cust2Lbs = Range("Q7")
  Set Output = Sheets("Sheet10").Cells(2, 2)
  Set OutputY2011 = Sheets("Sheet10").Cells(2, 3)
  Set OutputY2012 = Sheets("Sheet10").Cells(2, 4)
  Set OutputY2013 = Sheets("Sheet10").Cells(2, 5)
  Set OutputY2014 = Sheets("Sheet10").Cells(2, 6)
  Set YearD = Range("K6")

  For i = 0 To 14750
    If IsDate(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(6 + i, 11)) And IsNumeric(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(6 + i, 17)) Then
      If Year(YearD) = "2011" Then
        Total2011 = Total2011 + CustLbs.Value
        Output.Value = Cust.Value
        OutputY2011.Value = Total
      ElseIf Year(YearD) = "2012" Then
        Total2012 = Total2012 + CustLbs.Value
        Output.Value = Cust.Value
        OutputY2012.Value = Total
      ElseIf Year(YearD) = "2013" Then
        Total2013 = Total2013 + CustLbs.Value
        Output.Value = Cust.Value
        OutputY2013.Value = Total
      ElseIf Year(YearD) = "2014" Then
        Total2014 = Total2014 + CustLbs.Value
        Output.Value = Cust.Value
        OutputY2014.Value = Total
      End If

      If Cust.Value = Cust2.Value Then
        Set Cust = Cust.Offset(1, 0)
        Set Cust2 = Cust2.Offset(1, 0)
        Set CustLbs = CustLbs.Offset(1, 0)
        Set Cust2Lbs = Cust2Lbs.Offset(1, 0)
        Set YearD = YearD.Offset(1, 0)
      Else
        Set Cust = Cust.Offset(1, 0)
        Set Cust2 = Cust2.Offset(1, 0)
        Set CustLbs = CustLbs.Offset(1, 0)
        Set Cust2Lbs = Cust2Lbs.Offset(1, 0)
        Set Output = Output.Offset(1, 0)
        Set OutputY2011 = OutputY2011.Offset(1, 0)
        Set OutputY2012 = OutputY2011.Offset(1, 0)
        Set OutputY2013 = OutputY2011.Offset(1, 0)
        Set OutputY2014 = OutputY2011.Offset(1, 0)
        Set YearD = YearD.Offset(1, 0)
        Total2011 = 0
        Total2012 = 0
        Total2013 = 0
        Total2014 = 0
      End If
    Else
      Set Cust = Cust.Offset(1, 0)
      Set Cust2 = Cust2.Offset(1, 0)
      Set CustLbs = CustLbs.Offset(1, 0)
      Set Cust2Lbs = Cust2Lbs.Offset(1, 0)
      Set YearD = YearD.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Any help as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by using a MsgBox to verify your variables through each iteration. You may be able to pinpoint the problem this way.

> MsgBox (Cust & " " & Cust2 & " " & Total2011)

Answer (score 0):

You define `Total = 0` but then never change it before writing the value to your range here: `OutputY2011.Value = Total`

Your code appears to use a different total variable (i.e. `Total2011`) for each year instead:  Try changing your output like this (last line is the one I changed):

```
For i = 0 To 14750
    If IsDate(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(6 + i, 11)) And IsNumeric(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(6 + i, 17)) Then
        If Year(YearD) = "2011" Then
            Total2011 = Total2011 + CustLbs.Value
            Output.Value = Cust.Value
            OutputY2011.Value = Total2011
```